# Data Type Mismatch on vb.net and ms access

Tags: vb.net

```
If ComboBox1.Text = "New Student" Then

        Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to add the student as a " & ComboBox1.Text, "Added", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Command.Connection = Connection
            Command.CommandText = "UPDATE [Student] SET [Status] =@stat WHERE [RegistrationNumber] = '" & TextBox10.Text & "'"

            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat", ComboBox1.Text)
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Student Status is " & ComboBox1.Text)


            StudentRegister.loaded()
            StudentRegister.Show()

            Me.Hide()



        ElseIf result = DialogResult.No Then
            Me.Show()
        End If
```

I don't know what was the wrong with the code, (data type mismatch) please help. thank you.

Comment: What is the datatype for the Status and RegistrationNumber fields in your database?. You pass two strings here. And also could you explain why you use a parameter for one field and a string concatenation for the other field? Use always parameters

Comment: **Very** likely this: `WHERE [RegistrationNumber] = '" & TextBox10.Text & "'"`  If RegistrationNumber is a ***number** you are passing the value as text.  As mentioned always use SQL parameters

Comment: On which line of your code does it flag that error?

Comment: Thank You so much. I already fix the Error

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten this error several times but the problems is always coming from the values you are passing not corresponding with the datatype of that table in the db

In this case 
Command.CommandText = "UPDATE [Student] SET [Status] =@stat WHERE [RegistrationNumber] = '" & TextBox10.Text & "'

RegistrationNumber might be an integer in your db.

Passing it as

Command.CommandText = "UPDATE [Student] SET [Status] =@stat WHERE [RegistrationNumber] = val('" & TextBox10.Text & "')" would do the magic. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If ComboBox1.Text = "New Student" Then

```
    Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to add the student as a " & ComboBox1.Text, "Added", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Command.Connection = Connection
        Command.CommandText = "UPDATE [Student] SET [Status] = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' WHERE [RegistrationNumber] = '" & TextBox10.Text & "'"

        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Student Status is " & ComboBox1.Text)


        StudentRegister.loaded()
        StudentRegister.Show()

        Me.Hide()



    ElseIf result = DialogResult.No Then
        Me.Show()
    End If
```

''I Just redirected the ComboBox1.Text to the Command.CommandText instead of adding a Shortcut: (@stat)